# Jenkins JDK installation disappears after save and apply

Tags: jenkins

Here I add the setting and click apply and save.

[image]

But when I go back to the `Global Tool Configuration` it appears as if not configured. And if I click on the button I can see the settings I configured previously.

[image]

Needed to fix this so the jenkins will look for correct java home in slave machines.

Comment: After "Save", check the ${JENKINS_URL}/config.xml (use Chrome) and confirm they are actually saved. There are several reported issues where a different plugin prevents the loading of the saved values, which when the page is saved again, the blank values are now saved.

Comment: Also, by default the various tools in the Global Config show as collapsed (<Tool> ...) even when there are saved values; not sure if that's reported as a usability issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Jenkins version: 2.375.1**

1. You need to configure another [dummy JDK under Global Tool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnpRU.png) as following: JDKDisplayBug
2. After that, you can see the [list of your JDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXSuZ.png) under project configuration.